# Burninate the [user] tag

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, burninate-request

I think the [user](/questions/tagged/user) tag (x3565) should go away. In virtually every case, either a more appropriate tag such as [user-interface](/questions/tagged/user-interface), [username](/questions/tagged/username), etc. should be used, or the question involves doing *something* with a user, which is too general to make watching the [user](/questions/tagged/user) tag be of any use, or the question involves a "user" in the context of system administration, which is off-topic for SO.

Some recent examples include:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20027698/how-to-create-batch-file-to-copy-files-entered-by-user
  Of course data is entered by a user; the [user](/questions/tagged/user) tag adds no key information to this question.
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20017745/create-a-user-who-will-have-privileges-to-start-com-applications-on-windows-ser
  This is a server administration question.
- [Default logged in user to SQL Server column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20016651/default-logged-in-user-to-sql-server-column)
  The [user](/questions/tagged/user) tag, I believe, does nothing to help categorize this question. Incidentally, this is also [a case for getting rid of the [default] tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/207800/burninate-default).
- [How to get Windows username in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19990038/how-to-get-windows-username-in-java)
  The [user](/questions/tagged/user) tag was unnecessary. I removed the tag from this question and replaced it with [username](/questions/tagged/username) (which, in itself, seems rather questionable).

Those were just picked from the top of the list on the first page of results. That list goes on; I believe it is self-evident by looking at the questions currently tagged [user](/questions/tagged/user).