# Make inline [tag:] match text height

Tags: feature-request, tags, markdown, code-formatting

This is a minor request. I think it would clean up the formatting of a view questions if the inline tag element was represented as an object with the same height as the text, rather than with the full tag blocks.

The issue is that the tag blocks are rather large, vertically, and so it leads to inconsistent line spacing in text. For example:

- Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec 
  laoreet massa. Vivamus ac quam commodo, egestas mi et, pretium tellus.
  Integer fringilla risus quis libero lacinia auctor. Nulla facilisi. 
  Curabitur sit amet nisi purus. Suspendisse malesuada, odio ultricies 
  viverra rhoncus, mi magna eleifend nulla, id elementum diam orci at 
  orci. Nam purus libero, tincidunt id feugiat sodales, viverra vitae 
  purus. Quisque sit amet tempus dui, consequat [tempus](/questions/tagged/tempus) sapien. Nam
  vitae dapibus diam. Etiam non est nec enim facilisis porta. Nunc 
  porttitor bibendum lobortis. Aenean tincidunt quis nunc id venenatis. 
  Quisque et volutpat nisl. Sed congue, velit et malesuada volutpat, 
  nibh nibh rhoncus mi, ac tristique odio mi quis diam.

Having tags be rendered more similarly to, say, inline code blocks (but with the sans-serif font) would improve the situation (although even these are not perfect, but the effect is much less pronounced):

- Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec 
  laoreet massa. Vivamus ac quam commodo, egestas mi et, pretium tellus.
  Integer fringilla risus quis libero lacinia auctor. Nulla facilisi. 
  Curabitur sit amet nisi purus. Suspendisse malesuada, odio ultricies 
  viverra rhoncus, mi magna eleifend nulla, id elementum diam orci at 
  orci. Nam purus libero, tincidunt id feugiat sodales, viverra vitae 
  purus. Quisque sit amet tempus dui, consequat `tempus` sapien. Nam 
  vitae dapibus diam. Etiam non est nec enim facilisis porta. Nunc 
  porttitor bibendum lobortis. Aenean tincidunt quis nunc id venenatis. 
  Quisque et volutpat nisl. Sed congue, velit et malesuada volutpat, 
  nibh nibh rhoncus mi, ac tristique odio mi quis diam.

In particular, I found the formatting of [Burninate the [user] tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/207799/burninate-the-user-tag) to be rather unpalatable (another user edited the post to add proper tag markers).

Comment: Apparently this is done on mobile view. I thought you were playing a prank on me because I was having trouble finding the tag in the first blockquote.

Comment: +1 - This bothers me all the time; even happened to me [today](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20034797/splitting-html-string-into-two-parts-with-htmlagilitypack/20034997#20034997). Yes!

Comment: @animuson Sorry about that. I actually tried very hard to find a way to create indented text without a gray background for that example, but I could not. Also I should clarify, this is Chrome on Windows. I can include a screenshot instead if it is inconsistent across browsers, if you'd like.

Comment: I'm sure it's the same. Mobile just has completely different CSS that doesn't exhibit this problem.